# cannot read certificate file: /root/ssl/mongodb.pem MongoDB SSL ISSUE

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am unable to restart my `mongodb` service. On checking the logs at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` I get the following error :

```
cannot read certificate file: /root/ssl/mongodb.pem error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
2019-11-23T17:04:27.679+0000 F  CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration: Can not set up PEM key file.
```

My `/etc/mongod.conf` appears like :

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: /root/ssl/mongodb.pem
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

The permission for `/root/ssl/` folder is :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1354 Nov 23 16:22 mongodb.crt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1082 Nov 23 16:22 mongodb.csr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1679 Nov 23 16:21 mongodb.key
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mongodb mongodb 3033 Nov 23 16:22 mongodb.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1751 Nov 23 16:20 rootCA.key
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1472 Nov 23 16:21 rootCA.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb   17 Nov 23 16:22 rootCA.srl
```

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
MongoDB : 4.2
```

Comment: One of the way I was able to do this was to give user  `mongodb` permission for the specific directory. 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb <ssl_directory> and then I restarted the mongodb service and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

the folder `root` usually have the following permissions:

```
drwx------    5 root root  4096 Nov 25 15:32 root/
```

which means the user `mongodb` cannot access it in the first place.

my advice is to move the files in the `/root/ssl` folder to `/etc/ssl/mongodb/` and update the mongod.conf file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem and was confused because they expect 1 single file.

As you can see you link **.pem** but not the private key.

Just concatenate them `cat priv.key >> cert.pem` for me it started working right away.

[Check this detailed tutorial.](https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2020/05/02/securing-mongodb-cluster-with-tls-ssl/)

Answer (score -4):

change the content of mongod.conf file.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```